# Toggle background_opacity option in alacritty

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I want to bind key that switchs `background_opacity` value between 0.9 and 1.0 and immedialty shows the result in Alactitty terminal.
There is no action in key_bindings for this purpose.

I have `live_config_reload` enabled, so one possible approach is write zsh function, that will change  `alacritty.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened upon this question while looking for the same feature and ended up implementing it myself. I have included a demo of the working in my [blog](https://trunc8.github.io/2021/08/08/tut-toggle-alacritty-opacity).

For completeness, I will include the steps here.

###### ~/bin/toggle_alacritty_opacity

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## If alacritty.yml does not exist, raise an alert
[[ ! -f ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml ]] && \
    notify-send "alacritty.yml does not exist" && exit 0

## Fetch background_opacity from alacritty.yml
opacity=$(awk '$1 == "background_opacity:" {print $2; exit}' \
    ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml)

## Assign toggle opacity value
case $opacity in
  1)
    toggle_opacity=0.9
    ;;
  *)
    toggle_opacity=1
    ;;
esac

## Replace opacity value in alacritty.yml
sed -i -- "s/background_opacity: $opacity/background_opacity: $toggle_opacity/" \
    ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
```

Make the above script executable by running in the terminal:
`chmod +x ~/bin/toggle_alacritty_opacity`

Ensure that you have the following line in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`

```sh
## In order to use the executable scripts inside ~/bin directly
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now running `toggle_alacritty_opacity` from your terminal will toggle alacritty's opacity.

##### Bonus

If you're using i3 WM, append the following lines to `~/.config/i3/config`

```sh
## Toggling alacritty opacity in i3 (inside ~/bin)
bindsym $mod+Shift+a exec --no-startup-id toggle_alacritty_opacity
```

Now you have a key binding to toggle alacritty's opacity.